# AngularJS plugin for WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I am using AngularJS with WebStorm, and my question is:

How do I add the AngularJS plugin for intellisense keyword for the AngularJS directives in the JetBrains WebStorm?

Comment: https://github.com/johnlindquist/angularjs-plugin

Comment: it is resolved by applying the steps in webstorm from the above link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These links may help you:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971

http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/04/02/mastering-webstorm-for-angularjs-youtube-livestream-event-tuesday-april-9/

https://github.com/johnlindquist/angularjs-plugin

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/c_suah3j0Xc

http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/live-templates-for-angular-js-in-webstorm/

Answer (score 4):

Here is simple Steps to add Angular Plugin

Step 1 : Just download the JetBrains WebStorm plugin from http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971

Step 2 : Goto the WebStorm File->Settings->IDE Settings->Plugins

Step 3 : Click Install plugin from disk and select the zip files

Step 4 : Restart the WebStorm

You are done :)

Answer (score 0):

John recommends not to do it any other way than his but his instructions are as always a bit terse. I found this to be [a much better guide](http://www.codingcolor.com/javascript/adding-an-exisitng-angular-js-seed-project-to-webstorm-6-0/). It repeats what john suggests. Note that this step is easy to miss if you dont remember to scroll:
Navigate to the bottom of the panel and select the “Browse Repositories..” button. This spawns a new window. Double click on the Angular.js plugin