# Webstorm Angularjs plugin doesn't work, can't detect 'angular' keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I am new to Angularjs and web development.

I used Webstorm to develop it and installed angularjs plugin already. It seems work in html file, but it doesn't work in .js file. I have a very simple statement:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

In webstorm, it can't detect the keyword 'angular'.

Anyone knows what steps I am missing? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582539/angularjs-plugin-webstorm

It may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that the 'angular' is resolved in javascript embedded in HTML, but not in js files? Have you set up the angular js javascript library in any way? Seems that the library is either missing or configured in the HTML file scope only (the latter usually happens when using 'download library' intention in HTML file). To get the angular stuff resolved, you have to download the angular.js from http://code.angularjs.org and either copy it to your project directory or configure as a javascript library in Settings/javaScript/Libraries

Comment: For people like me who can't find things... https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html